# Parsing XML using json raises ValueError

Tags: python, json, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a XML file using xml ElementTree and json

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import json

def parse_file(file_name):
    tree = et.ElementTree()
    npcs = {}
    for npc in tree.parse(file_name):
        quests = []
        for quest in npc:
            quest_name = quest.attrib['name']
            stages = []
            for i, stage in enumerate(quest):
                next_stage, choice, npc_condition = None, None, None
                for key, val in stage.attrib.items():
                    val = json.loads(val)
                    if key == 'choices':
                        choice = val
                    elif key == 'next_stage':
                        next_stage = val
                    elif key == 'ncp_condition':
                        npc_condition = {stage.attrib['npc_name']: val}
                stages.append([i, next_stage, choice, npc_condition])
            quests.append( {quest_name:stages})
        npcs[npc.attrib['name']] = quests
    return npcs
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<npcs>
    <npc name="NPC NAME">
        <quest0 name="Quest Name here">
            <stage0 choices='{"Option1":1, "Option1":2}'>
                <text>text1</text> 
            </stage0>
            <stage1 next_stage="[3,4]">
                <text>text2</text> 
            </stage1>
            <stage3 npc_name="other_npc_name" ncp_condition='{"some_condition":false}' next_stage="[3, 4]">
                <text>text3</text>
            </stage3>
        </quest0>
    </npc>
</npcs>
```

But I'm having trouble with this bit:

```
<stage3 npc_name="other_npc_name" ncp_condition='{"some_condition":false}' next_stage="[3, 4]">
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    parse_file('quests.xml')
  File "C:/.../test2.py", line 15, in parse_file
    val = json.loads(val)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

It raises this error in the line `val = json.loads(val)` when `key="npc_name"` and `val="other_npc_name"`.

What's wrong with that? It didn't raise any error when `name="some string"`, but it does when `npc_name="some string"`.

I noticed that if I change `"other_npc_name"` to `'"other_npc_name"'` it doesn't complain, but this seem a bit hackish to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org/) is a way to store data structures - thus it can only decode said data structures.

When you try to get JSON to decode something like this:

> other_npc_name

JSON can't match this to any valid data type.  However, if this is wrapped in quotation marks:

> "other_npc_name"

JSON recognizes this as a String (as per the JSON spec, that is how a string is defined).

And this is what is happening in your script:

```
import json
print json.loads("other_npc_name") #throws error
print json.loads('"other_npc_name"') #returns "other_npc_name" as a Unicode string
```

Thus, it may seem 'hackish' to wrap the string this way, however, this is really the only way for JSON to decode it.

One potential suggestion is that if the npc_name attribute in XML is always a string, then pull it out as a string instead of trying to decode it as a JSON object.

Comment: Oh I see, I imagined that json would take the "other_npc_name" and try to decode it as a str, It makes a lot sense now.